# Can't span 12 columns within Twitter Bootstrap hero div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I am trying to span 12 columns within a hero and it is not working. My image that is on the right keeps going below my `h1` and `p` text if I span the text 8 columns and the image 4.

If I span the text 6 columns and the image 4 everything places fine. Below is my code:

```
        <div class="hero-unit">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span8">
          <h1>MISSION</h1>
          <p>Providing our clients with superior service.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
        <img src="img/american-flag.jpg" alt="American Flag" />
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checked out the document about offsetting the columns?  I tried your code with an image with width 301px and seemed to move over ok

```
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span8">
      <h1>MISSION</h1>
      <p>Providing our clients with superior service.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 offset6">
    <img src="images/facebook_logo.jpg" alt="American Flag" class="test"/>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Then i went into my css and did one of these:

```
.test           {
                 margin-top: -100px;
}
```

for moving the image up